# Remove object key and value inside of Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

My code =

This is my example data.

```
const songs = [
  {
    "title": "Just Once",
    "asset_id": "1f7e0fd8-db21-4c28-b9e1-eb0295af198c",
    "sort": 1,
    "performers": [
      {
        "last_name": "John",
        "first_name": "Doe",
        "group": {
          "group_id": "1e5f73fa-ffe8-4c70-a83b-84e7bf985b25",
          "dept_short_name": "PAO",
          "dept_long_name": "Public Affairs Office"
        },
        "email": "john@doe.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]

    const newTest= songs.map(( {...song} ) => (
        song.performers.map(({...group}) => group_id = group.group_id)
    ))
```

and I am getting this as result:

[image]

I should just remove the **dept_short_name** and **dept_long_name** from group object and the **group_id** will be remain, and the rest of the data of the **songs** should be remained the same.

**This should be the result:**

```
[
  {
    "title": "Just Once",
    "asset_id": "1f7e0fd8-db21-4c28-b9e1-eb0295af198c",
    "sort": 1,
    "performers": [
      {
        "last_name": "John",
        "first_name": "Doe",
        "group_id":"1e5f73fa-ffe8-4c70-a83b-84e7bf985b25"
        "email": "john@doe.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to recreate an object in both of your maps.

```js
const songs = [{"title":"Just Once","asset_id":"1f7e0fd8-db21-4c28-b9e1-eb0295af198c","sort":1,"performers":[{"last_name":"John","first_name":"Doe","group":{"group_id":"1e5f73fa-ffe8-4c70-a83b-84e7bf985b25","dept_short_name":"PAO","dept_long_name":"Public Affairs Office"},"email":"john@doe.com"}]}]

const updated = songs.map(({
  performers,
  ...song
}) => ({ ...song, // recreate song object
  performers: performers.map(({
    group: {
      group_id
    },
    ...performer
  }) => ({ ...performer, // recreate performer object
    group_id
  }))
}))

console.log(updated)
```

Comment: Works like magic! Nice.
I really need to loop and use spread to remain those data. Thanks, new knowledge for today.

Comment: @bossajie Glad I could help. BTW you might want to consider flattening your redux state to avoid nesting updates. Or there is a library [`immer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer) that makes the update code to look more imperative.

Comment: I am using this before sending to the API, because the API accepts group_id only, not object, and in my frontend using some 3rd party component, I need group object to display a proper one, that's why I am doing this.
Is that good practice?

Comment: I believe it is, unless you have a way to change API or frontend to match one another :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
    "title": "Just Once",
    "asset_id": "1f7e0fd8-db21-4c28-b9e1-eb0295af198c",
    "sort": 1,
    "performers": [
      {
        "last_name": "John",
        "first_name": "Doe",
        "group": {
          "group_id": "1e5f73fa-ffe8-4c70-a83b-84e7bf985b25",
          "dept_short_name": "PAO",
          "dept_long_name": "Public Affairs Office"
        },
        "email": "john@doe.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 delete songs[0].performers[0].group.dept_short_name;
 delete songs[0].performers[0].group.dept_long_name;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(songs))
});
```

This may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
const songs = [{
  title: "Just Once",
  asset_id: "1f7e0fd8-db21-4c28-b9e1-eb0295af198c",
  sort: 1,
  performers: [{
    last_name: "John",
    first_name: "Doe",
    group: {
      group_id: "1e5f73fa-ffe8-4c70-a83b-84e7bf985b25",
      dept_short_name: "PAO",
      dept_long_name: "Public Affairs Office"
    },
    email: "john@doe.com"
  }]
}];
songs.map(({ performers }, ind) => {
 performers.map(({ group }, ind) => {
  performers[ind].group_id = group.group_id;
 });

 delete performers[ind].group;
});

console.log(songs);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use delete keyword:
delete performerce ["keyname"]
It will return the Boolean value

Comment: Assuming this question has `redux` tag mutating state is not an option.